# Oracle SQL - Nominal Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've recently moved from T-SQL over to Oracle and some things are throwing me off.  One specifically I've searched a bit for is, Nominal Dates.

I have a DB which stores dates nominally (for example 42370 would be 2016-01-01)

Any thoughts on how to convert in Oracle? I previously used Convert(Datetime) with this in T-SQL.

Comment: And what value did you get when you did `convert(42370)`?  I would expect an error in SQL Server.

Comment: We are using a piece of software called Aspect/eWFM previously I used on SQL, but my new Employer has Oracle.  the 42370 was just a sample as the record would have anything from 2013 to future dates.  I'd like a 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates look like Excel dates, not a format generically recognized by SQL Server.

If so, you can convert to an Oracle date using the same logic you would apply in SQL Server or any other database:  Add the integer to 1899-12-31:

```
select (date '1899-01-01') + 42370
from dual;
```

Comment: Yeah, it's an odd DB from Aspect that stores it as this format. 
For Exampe:
SELECT
DD.START_NOM_DATE 
FROM
 tcsdbowner.EMP_GRP_ASS DD
Would return something like: 
35912
37104
37104
*Edit – I suck at formatting

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you!  I'm going to learn up on the dual feature.  Haven't come across this before either.  Thank you Gordon!

Comment: George - two comments:  First, realize that dummy is just convenience for selecting something when the data to be selected comes from functions and data in the SELECT statement itself.  In reality it is a one-row, one-column structure, just to provide a syntactically required target for the SELECT statement.  As for dates, please understand that oracle stores dates differently from MSSQL, DATE is a binary format that includes time, down to the second.  Read up on to_char and to_date functions in the Oracle SQL Reference.